# Dynamic injection of service (from within the controller)

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

I would like to dynamically inject some dependencies within a controller.
I can do it easily with the $injector like this:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.service('serv1', function() {
    var me = this;

  this.welcome = function(str) {
    console.log("Welcome " + str + "!");
  };
});

app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $injector) {
  var servMe = $injector.get('serv1');

  $scope.greeting = function() {
    servMe.welcome('Master Obi-wan');
  };
});
```

But, let's say that I have a huge service serv1 and do not want to 'bloat' my page if not required.
I would like to do it from within my controller (Plunker provided: http://plnkr.co/edit/Szs4Pg?p=preview)

The error I am facing is that the **$injector** does not seem to know about the newly loaded service. Should I refresh its cache or something? Should I instantiate a new one?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**script.js**

```
var app =angular.module('app', ['oc.lazyLoad']);
app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $injector,$ocLazyLoad) {
  // But not from inside the controller
  $ocLazyLoad.load('serv1.js').then(function(){
       var servMe = $injector.get('serv1');

  $scope.greeting = function() {
    servMe.welcome('Master Obi-wan');
  };

    });


});
```

**serv1.js**

```
angular.module('app',[]).service('serv1', function() {

  this.welcome = function(str) {
    console.log("Welcome " + str + "!");
  };
});
```

**HTML**

```
<html>

  <head>
    <link data-require="angular.js@1.5.3" data-semver="1.5.3" rel="stylesheet" href="Bootstrap" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.3" data-semver="1.5.3" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/oclazyload/1.0.9/ocLazyLoad.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
      <button ng-click="greeting()">Click me!</button>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thx! Any option not requiring an additional library.
Otherwise, would it be possible to lazy load the lazyloading library...? :)

Answer (score 1):

This code worked for me:

```js
app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $injector) {
  $injector.invoke(["ServiceName", function(service){
    $scope.service = service;
  }]);
}
```

The literal string could be any variable provided dynamically.
Source [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector).